# Vue: Why is this computed property not reactive?

Tags: vue.js

Here is a computed getter and setter from a vue component:

```
paidStartHours : {
    get() {
        return moment(this.position.paid_start, global.DB_DATETIME).format('HH');
    },
    set(value) {
        this.$store.commit({
            type : 'updatePaidStartHours',
            newValue : value,
            position : this.position
        });
    }
}
```

On get, it returns the hours (HH) from `position.paid_start`.  On set, it commits a store mutation, which essentially recreates the time string for `position.paid_start`.

In is bound (two-way) to an input as follows:

```
<input v-model="paidStartHours" type="text">
```

On initial load, computed property `paidStartHours` is correct (per Vue Tools).

When I update the input however, the value of `paidStartHours` does not change.  I know that the commit is successful, because the props that are handed to the component are correct.  It makes no sense to me.

EDIT:

The code in the `updatePaidStartHours` mutation has changed a number of times.  For example, I tried this:

```
updatePaidStartHours(state, payload) {
    payload.position.paid_start = 999;
}
```

The value of the passed prop changed to 999, however the value of the computed prop remained the same.

EDIT II:

I don't think it is worth trying to resolve this issue because I think my whole Vue  / Webpack / Node installation is very sick.  For example, this morning I delightedly followed this answer, [Vuejs and Webpack: Why is store undefined in child components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51254983/vuejs-and-webpack-why-is-store-undefined-in-child-components), to import an instantiated store into my App.  It all seemed fine but after about 8 hours of stuffing about I see that NO store properties are reactive.  I reverted to importing the config only, and now most of my store properties are reactive, but sadly not the ones above.  I think I need to abandon the approach until I get time to revisit blow away my Vue / Webpack / Node install and start again.

Comment: Can you show code of your `updatePaidStartHours ` mutation?

Comment: @ittus, see the edit heading.

Comment: You didn't change the state of vuex? Is it `this.position.paid_start = 999;`?

Comment: That's right @ittus.  this.position is a reference to an object in the store, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51257306/what-is-the-correct-way-to-update-an-object-reference-using-a-vuex-mutation

Comment: Where does your component get `position.paid_start` from? How is it set?

Answer (score 3):

Vuex mutations should be called from Vuex actions only - so in your code you should dispatch an action, not a mutation. Also, your mutation function is expected to mutate the `store` argument - not the `payload` one. Your getter is also wrong - it should use `this.$store.getters` and not your local component data.

```
paidStartHours : {
    get() {
        return moment(this.$store.getters.position.paid_start, global.DB_DATETIME).format('HH');
    },
    set(value) {
        this.$store.dispatch('updatePaidStartHours',value);
    }
}
```

Vuex module:

```
// initial state
const state = {
  position:
  {
    paid_start: null
  }
};

// getters
const getters = {
  position: (state) => state.position
}

// actions
const actions = {
  updatePaidStartHours ({commit}, payload)
  {
    commit('SET_START_HOURS', payload);
  }
}

// mutations
const mutations = {
  SET_START_HOURS (state, payload)
  {
    state.position.paid_start = payload;
  }
}
```